# How to create a character string using a vector of characters in R

Tags: r, string, apply

What is the best way of using a character vector, such as:

```r
vector <- c("36","944","38","994")
```

To generate a string like this:

```r
new_string  <- "x  == '36'| x  == '944'| x  == '38'| x  == '994'"
```

I tried using `paste0` but I am searching for a more efficient way to do this, i.e.

```r
paste0("x  == ", '36', "| x  == ", "944, "| x  == ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `%in%` here instead of `==` (assuming that the end goal is to subset a vector `x` based on the values in `vector`

```
 x %in% vector
```

If we want to use `==`, this can be done with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`|`, lapply(vector, function(u) x == u))
```

---

If the intention is to create a string, use `collapse` in `paste`

```
paste0('x==', "'", vector, "'", collapse = "|")
[1] "x=='36'|x=='944'|x=='38'|x=='994'"
```

Comment: Thanks so much akrun! 

Would you happen to know why I am getting a '\' when using collapse? 
Ie. 
 'x == \'1\'|x == \'2\''

Comment: @KatherineDrummond Maybe you added `"` instead of `'`

Comment: Apologies, still struggling. This is what I am running - looks identical to the suggestion. 
vector <- c("36","944","38","994")
paste0('x==', "'", vector, "'", collapse = "|")

Comment: @KatherineDrummond with that code, I am not getting the \ i.e. `paste0('x==', "'", vector, "'", collapse = "|")# 
[1] "x=='36'|x=='944'|x=='38'|x=='994'"`

Comment: How bizzare. Thanks for your help akrun

Comment: @KatherineDrummond I checked the output in R console with R 4.2.2.  Are you doing this on Rstudio

Comment: Editing code written a while ago on Jupyter notebook; R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit); Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Comment: @KatherineDrummond Probably the print in Jupyter could be different.  You may wrap with `cat(paste0('x==', "'", vector, "'", collapse = "|"))` and check if the `\` still present

Comment: Works! Absolute legend akrun. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

paste0 is actually efficient, as R is a vectorized language. Try this:

```
vector <- c("36","944","38","994")

paste0("x == '", vector, "'",collapse = "|")
```

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Please run these code above and see the outcome. The main difference is that the code above recycles any lengths of vector values; whereas the example code in the question manually wrote all of them out.

Comment: I see! Sorry I thought you are the author of the question - didn't realize you have answered this question already.